# Auto match highlight generator

Tags: android, web, conv-neural-network, ocr, faster-rcnn

I am doing work on the auto-match highlight generator, first, my question is on which platform should I create this, I have done it on a desktop application but it has some limitations, the second question is how should i detect the score box to identify the changes for the highlight, can it be done with OCR and the third question is that on which technique (CNN or RCNN) should I use to generate highlights?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sir, I am just looking for some guidance on the path to completing the automated highlight generation